How to use Terraform to grant AWS Lake Formation tag expressions
I am in need of some help with a project that I am stuck on. I have been tasked with codifying the deployment of AWS Lake Formation using Terraform. The last step I am struggling with is granting a tag expression to a list of roles.
Here is an AWS CLI example of the type of tag expression that I am trying to grant that uses AND as well as OR operators to require multiple tags/values in order to access an applicable resource:
aws lakeformation grant-permissions --principal DataLakePrincipalIdentifier=arn:aws-us-gov:iam::[account_number]:role/[role_name] --permissions "SELECT" "DESCRIBE" --permissions-with-grant-option "SELECT" "DESCRIBE" --resource '{ "LFTagPolicy": {"CatalogId":"[account_number]","ResourceType":"TABLE","Expression": [{"TagKey": "rel", "TagValues": ["rel_value"]},{"TagKey": "org", "TagValues": ["org_value1", "org_value2]},{"TagKey": "class", "TagValues": ["class_value1", "class_value2"]},{"TagKey": "handle", "TagValues": ["tag_value"]}]}}'

I have a tfvars file that contains a list of existing roles and the tags/values that I need the expression to assign. I currently have it configured like this:
 roles = {
  [role_name1] = {
    arn = "arn:aws-us-gov:iam::[account_number}:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/[region]/[role_name1]"
    tag_expressions = [
      {
        key    = "org"
        values = ["org_value1,org_value2"]
      },
      {
        key    = "class"
        values = ["class_value"]
      },
      {
        key    = "handle"
        values = ["handle_value"]
      },
      {
        key    = "rel"
        values = ["rel_value"]
      }
    ]
  }
  [role_name2] = {
    arn = "arn:aws-us-gov:iam::[account_number}:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/[region]/[role_name2]"
    tag_expressions = [
      {
        key    = "org"
        values = ["org_value1"]
      },
      {
        key    = "class"
        values = ["class_value"]
      },
      {
        key    = "handle"
        values = ["handle_value"]
      },
      {
        key    = "rel"
        values = ["rel_value"]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Here is my variables.tf file:
variable "roles" {
  description = "A map of roles with their ARNs and associated tag expresssions."
  type = map(object({
    arn = string
    tag_expressions = list(object({
      key    = string
      values = list(string)
    }))
  }))
}

Where I am having trouble is in my main.tf file, where I am trying to get Terraform to iterate through the list of the tag key and values variables and set up a single expression for each role that contains all of the tags. This is how I have things set up right now:
resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "table_tag_permissions" {
  for_each = var.roles

  principal = each.value.arn

  lf_tag_policy {
    resource_type = "TABLE"
    dynamic "expression" {
      for_each = each.value.tag_expresssions
      content {
        key    = expression.value.tag_key
        values = expression.value.tag_value
      }
    }
  }

  permissions = ["SELECT", "DESCRIBE"]

  depends_on = [aws_lakeformation_resource_lf_tags.db_tags]
}

The errors I get when running the terraform plan are:
Error: Insufficient expression blocks
│ 
│   on main.tf line 232, in resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "db_tag_permissions":
│  232:   lf_tag_policy {
│ 
│ At least 1 "expression" blocks are required.

Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 235, in resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "db_tag_permissions":
│  235:       for_each = each.value.tag_expresssions
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "tag_expresssions".

Any suggestions on how to correct these errors would be most appreciated. I have been losing my mind trying to figure out how to do this correctly.

I wouldn't use dynamic when an argument is required, because dynamic allows 0 or more blocks.

You have a typo each.value.tag_expresssions instead of each.value.tag_expressions (extra "s"). Unfortunately questions based on typos are not considered suitable for SO and are routinely closed/deleted, but glad I was able to solve your problem for you regardless.

@MarkoE If you don't recommend using dynamic, is there another way you would suggest that I could get this to work?

@MatthewSchuchard Thank you for spotting the typo. I have been looking at this for days and was so focused on having the syntax wrong that I couldn't see the spelling mistake.
